# TypeError: options.setContext is not a function in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, svelte

So I am using ChartJS in Svelte and I am trying to use date adapters as I have a time scale on the x-axis. My data looks similar to this.

```
[
  {
    "y": 21,
    "x": "2022-05-03T20:27:20.306Z"
  },
  {
    "y": 21,
    "x": "2022-05-03T20:27:50.759Z"
  }
]
```

And my code looks like this:

```
<script>
    export let freezer_data;
    import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';
    import Scatter from "svelte-chartjs/src/Scatter.svelte"
    import { enGB } from 'date-fns/locale';
    let data = {
      labels: ['Scatter'],
      datasets: [
        {
          borderColor: 'rgba(99,0,125, .2)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(99,0,125, .5)',
          label: 'V(node2)',
          data: freezer_data
        }
      ]
    };
  
    let options = {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Scatter Chart - Logarithmic X-Axis'
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
            type : "time"
        },
        adapters: {
        date: {
            locale: enGB
        }
    }
      }
    };
  
  
  </script>

      <Scatter {data} {options}/>
```

And I keep getting this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: options.setContext is not a function
```

Comment: is it resolved ? i am getting the same error

Comment: Getting same error... anyone resolved?